# Two listeners on one element: let only one fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

In situations where multiple event handlers are operating on a single element and action, how can I force only one of the events to fire? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/SpFKp/).

```
$("#buttons").on("click", "button", function(){
    // only do this if the event below isn't fired
});
$("#buttons").on("click", "button.red", function(){
    // if this one happens, don't do the above one
});
```

Comment: *Two Listeners One Element* sounds like the type of thing you'd like to see reaction videos about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a more general solution, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` will prevent the event from triggering any more handlers. For handlers bound to the same element, the order they are bound seems to matter. You could also bind the one that you conditionally don't want to fire to an element higher in the DOM and use `e.stopPropagation()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttons").on("click", ".red", function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        $(this).css("color","red");
    });
    $("#buttons").on("click", "button", function(){        
        $(this).css("background","blue");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ef5p7/

Here's how you could use `stopPropagation()` instead:

```
<div id="buttonsOuter">
    <div id="buttons">
        <button>turn blue</button>
        <button class="red">only turn text red</button>
        <button>turn blue</button>
        <button>turn blue</button>
        <button>turn blue</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttons").on("click", ".red", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    });
    $("#buttonsOuter").on("click", "button", function () {
        $(this).css("background", "blue");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CwUz3/

Answer (score 1):

Change the first event handler to:

```
$("#buttons").on("click", "button", function(){
    $(this).not('.red').css("background","blue");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SpFKp/3/)**

Comment: This event handler is still fired for "red" events. Even though you're applying the css only if it's not red, the original question was asking how to force only one event to fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttons").on("click", "button, button.red", function(){
    // if this one happens, don't do the above one
});
```

Comment: I think he needs different functions to be called for each.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:not()` http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttons").on("click", "button:not(.red)", function(){
        $(this).css("background","blue");
    });
    $("#buttons").on("click", "button.red", function(){
        $(this).css("color","red");
    });

});
```

Here's the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SpFKp/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,the functions will be called but you can add condition to not run the code:

```
var functionCalledFlag =false;
$("#buttons").on("click", "button", function(){
        if(!functionCalledFlag ){
           functionCalledFlag =true;
       // only do this if the event below isn't fired
     }else{
       functionCalledFlag =false;
     }

});
$("#buttons").on("click", "button.red", function(){
    if(!functionCalledFlag ){
           // only do this if the event above isn't fired
       functionCalledFlag =true;
     }else{
       functionCalledFlag =false;
     }
});
```